# PHP GD no webp support in docker

Tags: php, docker, gd

I always used GD to manipulate webp normally in my local environment, but when attempting to test my scripts in docker environment, i get `"Webp format is not supported by PHP installation."` error. I am using latest php version as in showed in my dockerfile below:

```
FROM php:8-fpm

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    pngquant

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
    chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user

# php.ini
COPY ./docker-compose/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/
```

What i am missing?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to install `libwebp-dev` and configure gd lib to support it:

```
RUN apt-get update && ... \
    apt-get install -y libwebp-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-webp;
```

The the examples here : https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/php#how-to-install-more-php-extensions

Comment: This is the corrent answer, but i wonder why webp doesn't come with gd specifically in docker? Itis comer by default in other installation methods. Anyway in the docs example, there other options that i don't know what they are about and if i should include them, such as freetype.

Comment: freetype is just another format (I think mostly for fonts). When you doesn't need it, don't install :) Not all PHP Application need GD with image support. so that's why in docker it is not included.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libwebp-dev;

## Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-webp;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).